# IP validation using RegularExpressionValidator not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I tried to implement the IP address validation using Required filed validator but it doesn't seem to work its displaying error **"Unrecognized Escape Sequence"**

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="txtadapterid" ErrorMessage="Please Enter a Valid IP Address" 
                            Font-Size="Small" 
                            ValidationExpression="^(([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}([01]?\d\d?|25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d)$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

and the code file method is

```
   private void checkRejex(string strFindin)
{
    Regex myRegex = new Regex("^(([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}([01]?\d\d?|25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d)$");
    if (myRegex.IsMatch(strFindin))
    {
        lblmsg.Text = "Valid Input";
        lblmsg.ForeColor = Color.Green;
    }
    else
    {
        lblmsg.Text = "Please enter a valid IP Address";
        lblmsg.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than a plain string with backslashes, as you have:

```
new Regex("^(([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}([01]?\d\d?|25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d)$")
```

you need to use a Verbatim String, prefixed with an `@`, like this:

```
new Regex(@"^(([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}([01]?\d\d?|25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d)$")
```

The `@` prevents the backslashes being interpreted as part of the string, but instead causes them to be passed through to the Regex as you intended.

See [String literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28VS.71%29.aspx) in the documentation for full details.

Answer (score 1):

In C# strings the backslash character (`\`) has a special meaning: it's an escape character. You need to use double backslashes to take away the special meaning:

```
"^(([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.){3}([01]?\\d\\d?|25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d)$"
```

Or use a verbatim string literal by prefixing it with @, where the backslash has no special meaning:

```
@"^(([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}([01]?\d\d?|25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d)$"
```

In verbatim strings only the double quotes (`"`) need to be escaped (again, by using a pair `""`) because they're used to delimit the string.